# Get the size of pictures in the pages after it called the onload resize function

Tags: javascript, image, dom, resize

I am trying to write an JavaScript to extract the pictures in the html whose width and height are  higher than a specified value. I use the DOM to extract the pictures. Here's the problem:

The pages that I want to extract has actually a JavaScript called "checkimagesize". Each  will call an onload function like:

```
<img src="./01_files/mobile01-cdbd8.jpg" id="http://attach.mobile01.com/attach/201112/mobile01-cdbd8.jpg" onload="checkimagesize(this.id,this.width,this.height)" />
```

After each  calls the "checkimagesize", I use DOM to extract the pictures. The width and height are all zero. (The pictures are reized by the onload function)

Does anyone know how to get the actual width and height of these pictures after it called the resize function?

Thank you very much.

```
function checkimagesize(image, wi, hi)
{
    var wo = wi + 40;
    var ho = hi + 40;
    var resize = false;
    var imax = 640;
    if (wi > imax) {
        rating = wi / imax;
        wi = Math.ceil(wi / rating);
        hi = Math.ceil(hi / rating);
        resize = true;
    }

    if (resize) {
        reimg = document.getElementById(image);
        reimg.width = wi;
        reimg.height = hi;
        reimg.onclick = function () {window.open(image, '', 'resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,width='+wo+',height='+ho);};
        reimg.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
}
```

my code:

```
listPics = document.images;
listPics[i].width 
listPics[i].height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to access the image properties before they have finished loading. Try executing your code after the window's `load` event (when all page elements have finished loading):

```
window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var img = document.images[i];  
        console.log("image size: " + img.width + "×" + img.height);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Julian D. I put the function after the windows's load event. then, it works! Thanks.